# Should I use sharding?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, partitioning, sharding

I'm looking for advice. I've never used sharding, but recently read somenthing about it and i suspect it should help with my long time execution queries in my database (PostgreSQL 9.1).

### Description

- I have table `posts` with 200 million rows.
- Each post has foreign key to `projects` table.
- Each project has from 100 to 300,000 rows in posts table (AVG: 30,000)
- Usually I execute queuries on the posts table joined with projects table on `projects_id` foreign key.
- I rarely execute join with pages from others table.

My queries (retrieving posts added in given period times and aggregations) are verly slow for projects with > 100,000 rows in pages.

### Should I use sharding?

If yes:

- How should I shard? Should I use `projects_id` in the pages table as a key?
- Is it enough to shard table pages (create posts_1, posts_2 ... tables)?
- Should I use several disks (partitions) on one machine (sharded tables on various disks)?

If not:

What should I use instead of sharding? I bought a server with faster disk (SAS); it helped but not enough. I've tried to use master-slave (with pgPool2), but when I want to execute longer query on the slave database, I get the following error:

> ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
>   DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.

### Detailed questions about sharding:

- How many rows should i have in each sharded table (posts_1,posts_2...)
- What is best solution/tool for sharding in PostgreSQL? Pl/Proxy?

Comment: 200 million isn't that much, why don't you try to optimize your queries? We use partitioning, a small partition has ~ 1 billion records and queries on these tables are fast enough.

Comment: Do you have a (projects_id, date_added) index on the table `posts`? If so did you `cluster` that table on that index?

Comment: Cluster on this index helped. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Well with out thorough bottleneck analysis and desired use cases  of the system its hard to tell. You never said exactly how slow its running.

I'll give you couple of options to consider instead of sharding:

1. Use a search engine such as **Solr** for common queries (like most recent)
2. Use counter tables or use something like **Redis** for statistic aggregates (num posts)
3. Use a message queue (Redis (pub/sub) or **RabbitMQ**) to throttle db writes
4. Cache, Cache, Cache
5. Lastly maybe consider a NoSQL option (highly doubt you need to do this)

If you have not done at least 3/5 options I mentioned you probably should not do sharding and look at the alternatives. Particularly number 2 as Postgresql is notoriously slow for things like: `select count(*) from ...`.